# How to get lottery results in json or xml format

Tags: xml, json

I am making an app which manages lottery number that you purchased and compare to winning numbers.
It will handle Powerball, Mega Millions and Superlotto Plus.
But I do not know how to get the winning numbers, drawing dates, amount and other info from its web site using 'http get'. JSON or XML format or whatever format.
Does anyone know how to get these data?

Comment: Hey @David, did you finish your App?

Answer (score 28):

Powerball lottery winning numbers are published on this website: [Lottery Powerball Winning Numbers](https://data.ny.gov/Government-Finance/Lottery-Powerball-Winning-Numbers/d6yy-54nr)

If you click on the Export tab, you get documentation for their API and also the API access endpoint (json) http://data.ny.gov/resource/d6yy-54nr.json

(PowerBall also publishes the winning numbers [here](http://www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt) as a plain text)

This is for Mega Millions: [Mega Millions Winning Numbers](https://data.ny.gov/Government-Finance/Lottery-Mega-Millions-Winning-Numbers/5xaw-6ayf)

I can't access SuperLotto plus, so I don't know if they offer any public api.

Comment: Is it necessary to use the access token and if so how is it placed in the URL thanks.

Comment: I don't think they need access tokens

Comment: For the SuperLotto there's an API that can be free if you don't need to make too many calls. Which you shouldn't: https://rapidapi.com/downtack-downtack-default/api/lottery-results/details

Comment: powerball.com has been updated and the free feed URL is not working anymore.